# How to Turn the navigation menu into a button when the width vary?

Tags: html, css

Hello there stackoverflow people, how is it going?

I noticed that in my website, when you open it with a not full size browser, the nav get a little messy. I see that, a lot of new websites have something that turn the navigation menu into a "3 bars" symbol, according the browser width. (just like in this wordpress theme: [Olam WordPress Theme](http://themes.layero.com/olamwp2/)

How can I do it? Can anyone give me a hint?

Thanks!

```css
body {
    background-color: black;
}


nav {
 padding: 12px;
 float: right;
 margin: 18px 100px;
}

nav a{
 margin-left: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #ffffff;
 font-family: Verdana;
 font-weight: bold;
 padding: 13px;
 font-size: 75%;
 letter-spacing: .03em;
}

nav a:hover {
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #0ad2ad;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
 <html>
  <head>
   <title>Navegation Doubt</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="first">
    <nav>
     <a href="#">Home</a>
     <a href="#">Store</a>
     <a href="#">Blog</a>
     <a href="#">Classes</a>
     <a href="#">Contact</a>
    </nav>
   </div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries) to apply different css rules based on different conditions (in your case the size of the device) basically you start by designing the site for the smallest device you wish to support then build out from there using min-width.

To get that three bar menu icon check out [font awesome](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/), they have some awesome icons you can use for your site.

Many css frameworks and grid systems include responsive components build using media queries, you can find a bunch of them [here](http://www.awwwards.com/what-are-frameworks-22-best-responsive-css-frameworks-for-web-design.html).

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing great! How about you?

They mainly used the navbar component (and the easiest way), from a CSS Framework called Bootstrap.
It is highly recommended to learn this framework, as it makes your site responsive.

Also, it is important to note that your navbar is the juice to your website's [SEO](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291).

After including Bootstrap, you can make the navbar, here is an example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
          Your Cool Website
          </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">Store</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Classes</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qdazh5qt/1/)